# Media Query for Mobile Devices, but not Retina Display

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, media-queries, retina-display

Right now I'm using the following media query, which has worked fairly well for my purposes (mobile devices).

```
    @media
    only screen and (max-width : 600px),
    only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
    only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5)
```

That is, until I found out that the pixel-ratio is actually triggering for a 13"? macbook w/ a retina display. So, my question is, is there a way to specify another constraint alongside the pixel-ratio, such as "a maximum pixel-width of 1080p" or something along those lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your media query has three conditions under which it will perform that CSS; you need to combine these to only capture mobile retina screens. Like so:

`@media (max-width : 600px), and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
    only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5)`

This sets two conditions which both say: "up to a maximum of 600px with a device pixel ratio of 1.5 or greater"

Comment: Thanks this seemed to work fine on the devices I tested with.